# ImageJ dialog path

Tags: path, dialog, imagej, imagej-macro

I have a Dialog asking for Preferences, in this Dialog I would like to aks for a path. I'm doing this: Dialog.addString("Saving directory", directory);
... I'm asking for lot more.

but I would like to have open up a new window, where you can search the path, like with this command but with more questions and answers in the Dialog.
path = File.openDialog("Select a File");

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using [Fiji](http://fiji.sc/Fiji), you can try its [`GenericDialogPlus` class](http://javadoc.imagej.net/Fiji/index.html?fiji/util/gui/GenericDialogPlus.html), e.g. in Javascript:

```js
importClass(Packages.fiji.util.gui.GenericDialogPlus);

gdp = new GenericDialogPlus("New dialog");
gdp.addDirectoryField("Directory", "/");
gdp.addCheckbox("Other option", true);
gdp.showDialog();
```

In plain ImageJ 1.x [macro language](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/macro/functions.html), the preferred way of asking for directories and additional parameters is to have several consecutive dialogs. Use `getDirectory("Choose a Directory")` to ask for a directory, and use the `Dialog` functions to ask for other parameters:

```bs
path = getDirectory("Choose a Directory");
Dialog.create("Choose parameters");
Dialog.addString("Title:", title);
Dialog.show();
title = Dialog.getString();

print path;
print title;
```

Comment: I edited my answer to include an option for plain ImageJ macros.